# How to parse lua table object into json?

Tags: json, parsing, lua

I was wondering if there was a way to parse a lua table into an javascript object, without using any libraries i.e require("json") haven't seen one yet, but if someone knows how please answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how to parse Lua tables to JSON strings take a look into the source code of any of the many JSON libraries available for Lua.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules

For example:

https://github.com/rxi/json.lua/blob/master/json.lua

or

https://github.com/LuaDist/dkjson/blob/master/dkjson.lua

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use any library and want to do it with pure Lua code the most convenient way for me is to use `table.concat` function:

```
local result

for key, value in ipairs(tableWithData) do
    -- prepare json key-value pairs and save them in separate table
    table.insert(result, string.format("\"%s\":%s", key, value))
end

-- get simple json string
result = "{" .. table.concat(result, ",") .. "}"
```

If your table has nested tables you can do this recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The are a lot of pure-Lua JSON libraries.
Even me have [one](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua).

How to include pure-Lua module into your script without using `require()`:

1. Download the Lua JSON module (for example, go to my [json.lua](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua/blob/master/json.lua), right-click on `Raw` and select `Save Link as` in context menu)
2. Delete the last line `return json` from this file
3. Insert the whole file at the beginning of your script
4. Now you can use `local json_as_string = json.encode(your_Lua_table)` in your script.